# What would be the IP if not mentioned in hostfile

Tags: networking, dns, hosts

If I ping the host say ABC and there isn't any host to IP mappings mentioned in the /etc/host file then what IP will it take?

P.S- The host that I am pinging belongs to an internal network.

Comment: If its not mapped to an IP address, then the "DNS" will not resolve to anything..

Answer (score 2):

No IP, in the event the other possible means of looking up an IP address from a hostname fail. Other possible means may be listed in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` on some flavors of unix, and include plain old DNS, zero-configuration multicast DNS lookup services (e.g. via avahi), cached entries from some previous lookup (positive or negative), and so forth.